# Paypal Checkout Button Loaded Multiple times

Tags: paypal, drupal-8

I have been integrated Express checkout with my Drupal 8 site. In my case I want show paypal button at once only and also I have loaded Checkout.min.js one time only through library. But here it has rendered 3 times as below.
[paypal button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfoJS.png)

While inspecting the js file, I could see checkout.min.js file loaded multiple times 
[as like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJuxf.jpg)

But I have loaded Checkout.min.js one time only through library like below,

```js
paypal_webform:
  version: 1.x
  css:
    theme:
      css/custom.css: {}
  js:
    https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.min.js: { type: external}
    js/custom.js: { preprocess: false }
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
    - core/jquery.once
    - core/drupal.ajax
    - core/drupal
    - core/drupalSettings
```

So please help me out, thanks in advance.